# Table of Contents with specfic lines without page numbers

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to add some lines to my TOC that aren't numbered. Say I have this document (see below) and I want the element `bar` not to be numbered in the TOC, but `foo` to be numbered. Is that possible?

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{foo}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{bar}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you can try `\addtocontents{toc}{{\protect\hspace{2.3em}bar}}` 2.3em to be adjusted

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, yes (realize I sould have been clearer on that)

Comment: @EricFail: Is the unnumbered entry really a `subsection`, or just something you want to add to the ToC under `\section{foo}`?

Comment: @Werner, good question! It's not really a `subsection`. This is a poor mans workaround. It's a range of themes that is covered in the given section (e.g in _foo_ I cover _bar_, _etc_.) that I am trying to list below the `section` entry in the TOC.

Comment: `\hspace` is robust so need to `\protect`.

Comment: @touhami: ??? Robust and then `\protect`? You mean it is not robust, I think?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer in my first comment I use  unnecessary `\protect`.

Comment: Are you using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)?

Comment: @Werner, not currently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the normal interface, defining a new command for the TOC:

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\l@sectionnote}[2]{%
  \begingroup\def\@dotsep{10000}%
  \@dottedtocline{2}{3.8em}{3.2em}{#1}{}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\toclevel@sectionnote}{100} % for avoiding a bookmark
\makeatother
\newcommand{\sectionnote}[1]{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{sectionnote}{#1}%
}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First}
\section{foo}

\sectionnote{Note about this section}

\end{document}
```

By defining `\@dotsep` to `10000`, the dots become invisible because they would go beyond the page margin. The group will restore the definition.

[image]

The code is compatible with `hyperref`.